# Fastest way to increment a BitArray (binary number) by one?

Tags: c#

The following "Increment" method is working perfectly. But I wanted to know is there any faster way to do this in less steps.

```
    public BitArray Increment(BitArray bArray)
    {
        carry = true;

        for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            if (carry)
            {
                if (bArray[i] == false)
                {
                    bArray[i] = true;
                    carry = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    bArray[i] = false;
                    carry = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return bArray;
    }
```

Thanks....

Comment: Is the `BigInteger` class better for your situation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx

Comment: You should be using `BigInteger` for this.

Answer (score 5):

There's one very obvious improvement you can make: stop when you're done!

```
public void Increment(BitArray bArray)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        bool previous = bArray[i];
        bArray[i] = !previous;
        if (!previous)
        {
            // Found a clear bit - now that we've set it, we're done
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you're *really* only got 32 bits (and will only ever have 32 bits), why not just use an `int` instead? Incrementing *that* is really easy! You could always wrap it in your own custom struct if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly write this in fewer steps and no branching:

```
bool newbit = bArray[i] ^ carry;
carry = bArray[i] & carry;
bArray[i] = newbit;
```

This bit of code can be generalised to a full adder, not just an incrementer.

Answer (score 1):

Without overflow handling:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 32 && !(bitArray[i] = !bitArray[i++]););
```

C-derived `for` loops always cry out for obscurity.